# Is it possible to resample and sum values in a Pandas dataframe by specifying a date range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following (dates with an associated binary value (whether or not a flood occurs), spanning a total of 20 years):

```
...
2019-12-27  0.0 
2019-12-28  1.0 
2019-12-29  1.0 
2019-12-30  0.0 
2019-12-31  0.0 
...
```

I need to produce a count (i.e. sum, considering the values are binary) over a series of custom date ranges, e.g. '24-05-2019 to 09-09-2019', or '15-10-2019 to 29-12-2019', etc.

My initial thoughts were to use the resample method, however as I understand this will not allow me to select a custom date range, rather it will allow me to resample over a set time period, e.g. month or year.

Any ideas out there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to get resampled dataframe only between selected date ranges, first you can filter your dataframe and than you can use resample methods. If you you want to resample datas between selected date ranges than you can filter and copy selected dates and than resample it and merge with original dataframe.

Comment: Just select the rows with `loc`, grab the column and sum. I could have provided an answer with the relevant code if only I could guess whether the dates are a column or an index, whether they are or not Timestamps, etc.

Comment: Thanks for these. @SergeBallesta yes the dates are a datetime index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dates are a DatetimeIndex and the index of the dataframe or Series, you can directly select the relevant rows:

```
df.loc['24-05-2019':'09-09-2019', 'flood'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a Pandas dataframe you should be able to do something like:

```
start_date = df[df.date == '24-05-2019']].index.values
end_date = df[df.date == '09-09-2019'].index.values

subset = df[start_date:end_date]

sum(subset.flood)   # Or other maths
```

where 'date' and 'flood' are your column headers, and 'df' is your dataframe. This assumes your dates are strings, and that each date only appears once. If not, you'll have to pick which date you want from the list of index values in 'start_date' and 'end_date'.